# Creating a new project in Eclipse using Maven as build tool for Google App Engine project

Tags: eclipse, maven-gae-plugin

I'm creating GAE projects and I would like to use Maven as build tool. I have found project http://www.kindleit.net/maven_gae_plugin/ that provides ability to use GAE with Maven, but I didn't understand how I can create a new project with this configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you have to have [m2eclipse plugin](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) installed to effectively use Maven in Eclipse. Once you have it:

- Create a new Maven project with `File`->`New`->`Project...`
- Make sure "Create simple project.." checkbox is not checked
- Select appropriate archetype from kindleit

[image]

- Give your project an id and a group

After that it will be generated with proper structure and dependecies

Comment: I cannot find net.kindleit from my eclipse, do I have to install something else than just m2eclipse plugin ... ?

Comment: You probably have to refresh your repository index. Open `Maven Repositories` view. Open `Global Repositories` and right click on `Central`. Enable Full Index and then rebuild it. It'll take few mins initially to download the index. After that you should easily find any dependency, plugin or archetype.

Comment: Also you can configure Eclipse (see Maven preferences) to download repository index updates on startup.